# How can I change json format selected from mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, json

I am doing a select query on MySQL database using NodeJS.
How can I get the expected result? I want to erase >> {title:} <<

What I want:

```
['test1','test2']
```

My code:

```
app.get('/info', function(request, response){
   var query = 'SELECT title FROM community';
   db.query(query, function(err, filelist, fields){
   if(err) console.log(err);
      console.log(filelist);
      console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(filelist));
});
```

The result I got:

```
[ TextRow { title: 'test1' }, TextRow { title: 'test2' } ]
[ { title: 'test1' }, { title: 'test2' } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const titleArr = filelist.map(item=>item.title);
```